# Override "release" or "dealloc"

Tags: objective-c, ios

Which is the best method

Override "release" or "dealloc" method in objective c?

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under non-ARC, 99% of the cases you should not override the release method.

I have seen only 1 case that the need to override the release method - a kind of singleton, which forces the class have really 1 single instance no matter how many times you call alloc.

That way override not only the `release` method, but also `allowWithZone:`, `retain`, 'retainCount`, etc. (It is actually not common to implement that kind of singleton)

Comment: There are plenty of cases under ARC where you want to override the `dealloc` method... For instance, if you want to unsubscribe from any observation mechanism (KVO, Notification Center...)

Comment: "Under ARC, you shouldn't override either methods." - this is wrong.

Comment: @PeterWong You're welcome, thanks for having updated your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Which is the best method? Override the `release` or the `dealloc` method?

`- dealloc`, definitely. You should never override `- release`.

> Why?

One, because `release` does a bunch of internal stuff. Two, *because if `release` is called, it does **not** mean that the object is deallocated.*

So you would release your ivars or null your properties by accident. And who wants an ugly segfault when we can have worldpeace instead?

If an object is really deallocated, `- dealloc` will be called.

Comment: dont rely on dealloc for anything non memory related though .. e.g. closing sockets

Comment: @Daij-Djan Well, I think that depends on. Objects realize encapsulation, and if a destructor needs to close a socket, then it needs to close that socket...

Comment: yes but the runtime makes no guarantees when (arc can optimize the timing) or if it is called... e.g. when an app is quit it... actually that the only sensible reason I can see right now

Comment: You say "don't override release" and give one reason as "because if release is called, it does not mean that the object is deallocated".  This seems like a non-sequitur to me.  There may be reasons for overriding release that don't depend on any expectation that the object would be deallocated.  Agree that release does a bunch of internal stuff, and it would surely be important for any override to call the base implementation for that reason.  You go on to say that one would release ivars & null properties by accident.  Who says?  Nobody suggested they'd do that.

Comment: @Martin If you think a bit about OP's question, it's clear that he's not an advanced memory management guru. He essentially asked which which method of the two is the destructor. And I answered that perfectly well.

Comment: @H2CO3 You may be right, but I re-read the question and still don't read it the way you do.  If you're right about what he's asking then you're also right about the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ARC, you should override the `-[MyObject dealloc]` dealloc method to release all retained objects inside your object. I have never found a case where I needed to override the release method.

If you are using ARC, you can usually avoid overriding the -dealloc method at all, unless you are using anything that ARC won't free up like a sqlite pointer or something.

Answer (score 0):

**dont override either for anything not relating to memory management** - you dont when and if those methods even get called.

**exceptions** for when you should dealloc:

- removing KVO / notification center observer
- deallocating manually allocated memory (arc) / release your ivars (non-arc)

Comment: :P read my exceptions before making a snide comment ;) maybe I reformat my answer though ;)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you were making exceptions - I now realize you were right.