# Timestamp of object creation, it's possible?

Tags: objective-c, object, memory, timestamp

Just for curiosity...
It's possible to know the timestamp of an object creation in Objective-C or others languages?

```
[_MyObj creationTime] ?
```

Comment: `Note: please don't downvote` - Don't ask this. If it's a bad question, I'll downvote it, if it's a good question, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put that in an object's `init` method

```
creationDate = [NSDate date];
```

given you've declared `NSDate *creationDate;` in `@interface` of the object

now you can retrieve the precise time

```
- (NSString *)creationTime
{
   NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
   timeFormatter.dateFormat       = @"HH:mm:ss";
   NSString *timeString           = [timeFormatter stringFromDate: cretionDate];

   return timeString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly by using constructors/destructors to save timestamps.

Comment: objective-c doesnt have cons/dest :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya objective-c DOES have constructors and destructors. They are called "alloc/init" and "dealloc".

Comment: but from my c++ knowlege, you can call box() and ~box() for class box.  But in obj-c you can. in obj-c they are just fake names that resembles like cons/desc, but actually they arent. I may be wrong. but i read this somewhere

Comment: -init is good, but -dealloc not so much.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563050/override-release-or-dealloc/13563136#comment18600861_13563136

Comment: He said "in Objective-C or others languages"

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the class and add a new ivar (say createdOn), and in the constructor or init method of that save current time.

So that you can call that object.createdOn anytime....